# NodeJS/ExpressJS/MongoDB Simple API Errors

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to make a simple API with NodeJS/ExpressJS, and mongoose.

I am getting the error: `No default engine was specified and no extension was provided`

The API will call the cat API. Since it only supports XML, it will convert to JSON, then will insert into mongoDB, then the JSON returned to the client is to be formatted in a very specific way. Currently, I am having issues. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var History = mongoose.model('History');
var request = require("request");
var convert = require('xml-js');
const util = require('util')

router.get('/cat', function(req, res, next) {
    var url = "http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=xml&type=jpg"
    var result = request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
        return body;
    });

    var options = {ignoreComment: true, alwaysChildren: true, compact: true};
    var result_get = convert.xml2js(result, options);

var image = result_get['response']['data']['images']['image']
var url_data = image['url']['_text']
var id_data = image['id']['_text']
var source_url_data = image['source_url']['_text']

console.log(
    id_data ,
    url_data ,
    source_url_data 
);

var history = new History()
//hardcode user for now
history.user = "1"
history.url = url_data 
history.id = id_data 
history.source_url = source_url_data 
history.save(function(err, history){
    if(err) {
        return res.send(500,err);
    }
    var history_json= res.json(history);
    var returned_json = {}
    var key = 'image'
    returned_json[key] = {}
    var data = {
        url: url_data,
        id: id_data,
        source_url: source_url_data
    }

    returned_json[key] = data
    console.log(JSON.stringify(returned_json))

    return res.json(returned_json);

    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

The returned JSON should look like this:

```
{
  "image": {
    "url": "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m3ay3e1zHp1qcxyrro1_1280.jpg",
    "id": "c11",
    "source_url": "http://thecatapi.com/?id=c11"
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you get in your `console`?

Comment: You've got a lot going on here.  Most of your code is outside of your `request` callback which means that it will get executed before the callback occurs.  I'd recommend taking a step back and getting one thing working at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you describe is probably not related to the code you posted because you don't render anything. But seems like somewhere in your application you use `res.render`. If this is the case - you will need to set a view engine.

Re, the code you posted:

1). You cannot return body from inside the `callback` function passed in `request.get`.
The `body` is only defined inside the callback function, you will have to wrap the rest of your code inside this callback function. Or, alternatively, you can wrap the rest of your code inside a function and call it in the `callback` function:

```
request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
    handleRes(body);
});

function handleRes(result){
/*.. the rest of your code goes here */
}
```

2). You cannot call again `res.send` once you called it, because `res.send` ends the response.

Comment: Thanks this is how I ended up doing it. I was just trying to make the code less messed. Callbacks within callbacks just look ugly.

Comment: You can use `Promise` if you want.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but I'd have to re-write everything. Maybe I will. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a view engine since you are just writing a backend server returning only JSON responses. In your index.js file (or wherever your server is running), comment out the following line.

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```